# passing a multi dimensional array to Insert in Codeigniter Model

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, model, associative-array

```
{
    "word": ["w1", "w2"],
    "meaning": ["m1", "m2"],
    "parts_of_speech": ["p1", "p2"],
}
```

This is the Data i have in Model which is now assigned to **$data** variable

In above **$data** each **word** index has corresponding Meaning in **meaning** array, and each **word** index has corresponding **parts_of_speech** in **parts_of_speech** array index. In this way always length of **word,meaning,parts_of_speech** arrays remain same

I have tried the following methods to insert into table

```
$this->db->insert('table_words', $data); 

$this->db->insert_batch("table_words",$data);
```

but it happened errors

Comment: why don't you stick to array structure as explained in userguide for insert_batch()? https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data

Answer (score 0):

CodeIginter accepts array for insert in which key should be 'column name' and value value should be record which we want to insert. As i can understand you have to insert multiple rows, So you have to use batch insert. 
Try below code :

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'word' => 'w1' ,
      'meaning' => 'm1' ,
      'parts_of_speech' => 'p1'
   ),
   array(
      'word' => 'w2' ,
      'meaning' => 'm2' ,
      'parts_of_speech' => 'p2'
   )
);
$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```

Your json should be like this

`[{"word":"w1","meaning":"m1","parts_of_speech":"p1"},{"word":"w2","meaning":"m2","parts_of_speech":"p2"}]`

Comment: how can i generate this $data array From Controller

Comment: Your data should be like above format for insertion. Codeigniter support above array for insertion. Make your json format like above and then decode it in array. After that you have to just pass that array.

Comment: @MithunSudheendran Post your answer here for someone who may come up with same problem.